# About image span save

Tags: android

```
ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(getInstance(), RichTextImage.getBitmap(getWindow(), path));
```

This imageSpan is added to the edittext, and now if i use `Html.toHtml(getEditableText());`:
the output is `<img src="null">`.

Comment: What are you expecting the HTML to contain? The image does not exist outside of that `Bitmap`.

Comment: Such as....The iamge path is ***, I want it output `<img src="****" />` instead of null src.

Comment: Actually, I just want to save and load the rich text.

Comment: Then do not put images in that rich text, or handle your own HTML conversions. `ImageSpan` has no idea where the `Bitmap` came from, and neither does `Html.toHtml()`.

Comment: So how should I do to solve this problem? I do need to put image to edittext, because this is a rich editor like many apps.

Comment: "So how should I do to solve this problem?" -- then handle your own HTML conversions, and interpret `ImageSpan` however you wish. The source code to `Html` and `HtmlCompat` are available. In the end, a `Spanned` object is merely a data structure, consisting of text and spans. You can convert that data structure to some other format (JSON, HTML, etc.) as you see fit.

Comment: Is there any existed examples? I have no idea to do this. You mean I can change the Editable to Spanned and convert it to other format? How could I know the image path of the ImageSpan?